# mapply over a function yields erronoeusly the aplication of another function

Tags: r

I am attempting to create a filter to apply to a time series. For reasons I have been trying but failed to understand when I apply a function (fir1) the package applies another function (fir2) from the same package and makes an error (which is Ok as the fir2 function is uncomplete) - http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/signal/signal.pdf - . There are no conflicting packages. When the function is applied without applying mapply then it works fine. I believe Mapply is the right overlaping function to apply. I also attempted to use expand.grid as to combine all variables with the same result. My question is if is possible and if so and how could use fir1 with mapply for the expresión below.

```
library(signal)
N<-list(c(8448, 6034 ,3520,  960,  899,  704), c(6034, 3520, 2485, 1083,  960,  899,  704))

Rup<-list(c(0.03925781, 0.05496094, 0.09421875, 0.34546875, 0.36902344, 0.47109375),c(0.05496094, 0.09421875, 0.13347656, 0.30621094, 0.34546875, 0.36902344, 0.47109375))

Rdown<-list(c(0.03886719, 0.05441406, 0.09328125, 0.34203125, 0.36535156, 0.46640625),c(0.05441406, 0.09328125 ,0.13214844, 0.30316406, 0.34203125, 0.36535156, 0.46640625))

L<- seq(1:length(N))
LL <- function(x) seq(1:length(Rdown[[x]]))
LLL<-lapply(L,LL)

n <- function (x,y) round(3.3/(Rup[[x]][y]-Rdown[[x]][y]))
N <- mapply(n,L,LLL)

F<- function(x,y) fir1(N[[x]][y]-1, c(Rdown[[x]][y], Rup[[x]][y]), "pass", scale = TRUE)
FILTER <- mapply(F,L,LLL)

#Error en fir2(n, f, m, 512, 2, window) : 
#frequency must be nondecreasing starting from 0 and ending at 1
#Además: Mensajes de aviso perdidos
#1: In if (n == 1) c = 1 else { :
#la condición tiene longitud > 1 y sólo el primer elemento será usado
#2: In 0:n :
#expresión numérica tiene 6 elementos: solo el primero es utilizado

#the same error occurs 
LLLL<-expand.grid(L=L,LLL=LLL)
F<-mapply(function(x,y)  fir1(N[[x]][y]-1, c(Rdown[[x]][y], Rup[[x]][y]), "pass", scale = TRUE),LLLL$L,LLLL$LLL)

#when applied directly it works fine. 
fir1(N[[1]][1]-1, c(Rdown[[1]][1], Rup[[1]][1]), "pass", scale = TRUE)
```

Any help is welcomed

Comment: `fir1(N[[1]][1]-1, c(Rdown[[1]][1], Rup[[1]][1])` is not the same as `fir1(N[[x]][y]-1, c(Rdown[[x]][y], Rup[[x]][y])`

Comment: The last example was done to show that the function works when index values are applied to it and not when using mapply.

Comment: You are using `L` and  `LLL` inside your function `F` as indices, so the first element of `L`, which is 1, and the first element of `LLL`, wich is a vector ` 1 2 3 4 5 6`

Comment: Thans for your help, I was seeing this. I am trying to find out if there is a way to pass the vector for LLL with L into the maply function but I guess there is no way in the present form which I though it was posible as I had passed the same for the N mapply function above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply directly you should not look at `N[[1]][1]-1`  and `c(Rdown[[1]][1], Rup[[1]][1])` but at:

```
v1 <- N[[L[[1]]]][LLL[[1]]]-1
> v1
[1] 8447 6033 3519  959  898  703

v2 <- c(Rdown[[L[[1]]]][LLL[[1]]], Rup[[L[[1]]]][LLL[[1]]])
> v2
 [1] 0.03886719 0.05441406 0.09328125 0.34203125 0.36535156 0.46640625 0.03925781 0.05496094 0.09421875 0.34546875
[11] 0.36902344 0.47109375
```

If you look at the arguments of the function `fir1` you can read about the first argument `n`:

```
n    order of the filter (1 less than the length of the filter)
```

So, it should be one number, and not a vector as `v1`.

And about the seccond argument `w`:

```
w    band edges, strictly increasing vector in the range [0, 1]...
```

but as you can see and check on v2, this condition is not fulfilled:

```
sum(!diff(v2)>=0)
[1] 1
```